# Shiny: fileInput looks different within a dashboardPage or within a fluidPage?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am making a shiny app where the UI is a dashboardPage from "semantic.dashboard" package.
I noticed that fileInput looks normal when I put it within a fluidPage but when I put it within a dashboardPage, it has a different look, essentially, it has no button for "browse" and the style is very... "minimalist". What can I do in order to make a dashboardPage fileInput look just like it would in a fluidPage?

[In a fluidPage: fileInput looks perfectly okay.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dwFl.jpg)

[In a dashboardPage: why does it appear buttonless, why does it look so weird ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEgjw.jpg)

I tried both Chrome and Microsoft edge as browsers but this issue seems to be independent of the browser choice. I also thought it could be a CSS issue but trying different styles never changed the look of fileInput itself.

Below is the code I would like to modify in order to to that.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(semantic.dashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(title="Home",suppress_bootstrap=TRUE,
                   dashboardHeader(color="red", inverted=TRUE),
                   dashboardSidebar(
                     size="thin", color="teal",
                     
                     sidebarMenu(
                       menuItem(tabName="download", "Download", icon=icon("download")),
                       menuItem(tabName="upload", "Upload", icon=icon("upload")),
                       menuItem(tabName="main", "Main", icon=icon("car")),
                       menuItem(tabName="extra", "Extra", icon=icon("table"))
                     )
                   ),
                   dashboardBody(
                     
                     tabItems(
                       selected=1,
                       tabItem(
                         tabName="download",
                         sidebarPanel(
                           fileInput("directory_export", "Choose output location",
                                     accept = c(
                                       "text/csv",
                                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                       "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                                       ".csv"),
                                     multiple=TRUE,
                                     buttonLabel="Browse",
                                     placeholder="Loading..."
                           )
                         )
                       ),
                       tabItem(
                         tabName="upload",
                         
                       ),
                       tabItem(
                         tabName="main",
                         
                       ),
                       tabItem(
                         tabName="extra",
                         
                       )
                     )
                   ), theme="cerulean"
)

server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you have an idea, thank you !

Comment: I think it may be an issue with the semantic.dashboard package.

Comment: @Typer Writer If so, what package would you use to make fileInput look normal within something that looks like this Dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

The "shinydashboard" package allows fileInput to display correctly. I guess semantic.dashboard needs some updates.

[It works like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMm71.jpg)